# What is the correct term for a function that accepts its argument in different data types?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic

Lately I was struggling to explain the way a certain method works to a colleague of mine. The problem was related to me not knowing a certain term (that probably exists). Take a function like this:

```
function myFunct (arg) {
    if (typeof arg == "number") {
        // ...
    }

    if (typeof arg == "string") {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Depending on the datatype of `arg`, the method does something different. What is the correct term for such a function that accepts its argument in different data types?

Comment: I want to say "dynamic dispatch function" here, but I know that's not its formal name. I'm not sure that it has one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "polymorphism", here is the definition from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)):

> ... polymorphic functions that can be applied to arguments of different types, but that behave differently depending on the type of the argument to which they are applied (also known as function overloading or operator overloading)

In statically-typed languages, like C++, it is possible define multiple functions with the same name, but different arguments. For example `myFunct(int arg)` and `myFunct(string arg)`.

In dynamically-typed languages, like php or python, the function can accept a parameter of any type and do things differently depending on the type like in your example.

Comment: Not sure, I would rather call it *fake polymorphism* because the example shown is not really an overloaded function. It just checks the type of the argument and then does different things. In real polymorphism - as I understand it, different functions (same name but different implementations) would be called depending on the type.

Comment: While doing some research I often found the term "functional polymorphism", often used related to languages, that don't support real polymorphism.

Comment: @Sven, can you provide a link that explains _functional polymorphism_?